# Outputting numbers' ASCII character in Assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, ascii, emu8086

I'm having problem outputting the calculated value in each step of Fibonacci sequence calculation, it outputs the respective ascii character of the calculated value like ☺ ☻ ♥ ♣ and how many times the sequence should run is depended on the user however it's limited to 47:

```
org 100h

ask_for_input db " Please enter a number[1-47]: ","$"
inputNumber DB 0  
conv DB 10D 
newL DB 0AH,"$"      


ask-again:        
    LEA DX, newL
    MOV AH,9H
    int 21H       

   ; Ask for user input       
   LEA DX, ask_For_input                       
   mov AH,9H
   int 21H             

   ; Gets user input
   ; First digit           
    MOV ah, 01H          
    int 21h

    SUB AL, 30H
    MUL conv   
    MOV inputNumber, AL

    ; Second Digit
    MOV AH, 01H 
    int 21h

    SUB AL, 30H
    add inputNumber, AL

    ; Checks if number is above 47D
    CMP inputNumber, 2FH
    JNLE ask-again  
    ; Checks if number is below 00D
    CMP inputNumber, 00H
    JLE ask-again    

; Squence loop Counter                      
MOV CH, 00H
MOV CL, inputNumber 

; Starting calculation
prev DB 01D   
current DB 1D            

Begin:
   space DB " ","$"
   LEA DX, space
   MOV AH,9H
   int 21H    

   ; Print Current Number                            
   LEA DX, current,"$" 
   mov AH,09H
   int 21H 

   ; Finds next number
   MOV BL, prev
   add current, BL 

   ; Advances prev
   MOV BL, current
   SUB BL, prev
   MOV prev, BL             

   Loop Begin
```

Comment: You should definitely not place data in the code execution path. Put them after all code. As far as the printing is concerned, `int 21h / ah=09h` is used to print strings. So you'll have to convert your number into a string. There are plenty of questions on how to do that already, so do some searching.

Comment: And what is `LEA DX, current,"$"` supposed to do? Does that even assemble?

Comment: @Michael I'm actually new to assembly and this what I have seen the text book the tutor has just given out about outputting strings to the console

Comment: @Michael and what do you mean by not placing data in the code execution path?

Comment: I mean mixing code and data. The CPU doesn't know the difference and will not automatically skip over data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Always place the data outside of the execution path. Now you've placed the data for *prev*, *current*, and *space* between the instructions. This will lead to failure.

  ```
  ask_for_input db " Please enter a number[1-47]: ","$"
  inputNumber   DB 0  
  conv          DB 10D 
  newL          DB 0AH,"$"      
  prev          DB 01D   
  current       DB 01D,"$"            
  space         DB " ","$"
  ```
- In order to actually print the number you need to convert it to a character. Your *current* variable holds a binary value, not a character! This quick solution will display the single digit Fibonacci numbers only:

  ```
  ; Print Current Number                            
  add current, 30H
  LEA DX, current
  mov AH,09H
  int 21H 
  sub current, 30H
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but since we ask user to input a number between 1-47 the result will be more than 1 digit for sure

Comment: That's why I said you need to convert it. Search for a conversion routine.

Comment: I have actually came up with a conversion mehod myself, I'll post it once I have written the code

Comment: Also note that using byte sized variables will not allow for those 47 Fibonacci numbers! You'll need to use doublewords for that.